# Unable to parse the JSON string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the JSON file input.json:

```
{
"consumner_key": {
    "display_name": "CONSUMER-KEY:",
    "name":"consumer_key",
    "format": "string",
    "type": "textbox",
    "isMandatory": "true"
},
"secret_key": {
    "display_name": "CONSUMER-SECRET:",
    "name":"consumer_secret",
    "format": "string",
    "type": "textbox",
    "isMandatory": "true"
}
}
```

I am using `$.getJSON()` to get the JSON file and parse it:

```
$.getJSON('input.json',function jsonData(Data)
{
$.each(Data, function(m,field) 
        {
            console.log(m);
            $('#tabs-4 social').append('<input></input>').attr({type:'text',name:this.consumner_key+''+this.name});
            $('#tabs-4 social').append('<input></input>').attr({type:'text',name:this.secret_key+''+this.name});
        });

});
```

When I run it I am not able to view the input boxes in my tabs. Kindly point to where I am going wrong.

Comment: It would help if you posted the console output with the javascript errors...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to clear all the errors.Specifying MIME type in web.xml of tomcat was not enough.I had to manually override it in my js file.The below code removed the error "not well formed"

```
$.ajaxSetup({beforeSend: function(xhr){   
if (xhr.overrideMimeType)  
{     
    xhr.overrideMimeType("application/json");}
} 
});
```

Also I was refering the json files both in my jsp and javascript file which was causing the invalid label errors

Answer (score 2):

you say you have file `input.js`, but in the code you have `input.json` - can that be a reason?

**UPDATE**

You also give name to your function - `jsonData`. As far as I know you should not name inline javascript functions, it will not compile. Just do

```
$.getJSON('input.json',function (Data) {
    $.each(Data, function(m,field) {
        console.log(m);
        $('#tabs-4 social').append('<input></input>').attr({type:'text',name:this.consumner_key+''+this.name});
        $('#tabs-4 social').append('<input></input>').attr({type:'text',name:this.secret_key+''+this.name});
    });

});
```

**UPDATE 2**

Furthermore, you do `this.consumner_key+''+this.name` and `this.secret_key+''+this.name`, while `consumner_key` and `name` are properties of different levels. I believe, `this` inside `each` should represent each single sub-object inside your json object. So it will have property `name`, but not `consumner_key`. I may be wrong, but anyway `this` cannot have both properties.

Comment: sorry.. made a mistak while typing the question.My json file is input.json

Comment: I tried but no success..futher its says invalid_label "consumer_key:" and also not well formed "{" I checked my jsonscheme with online validators.Its a valid JSON. Also I added the MIME type- application/json in tomcat under web.xml. still no success